# Only the first "other" reason for a downvote is shown, all others are lost (or hidden)

Tags: bug, documentation, user-interface

I found [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/37/null-coalescing-operator/3073/null-coalescing-operator-with-method-calls#t=201607270853126105338) that I thought was essentially repeating previous examples in the topic. Said example already had an improvement request flagged on it, but I thought the example was bad in a different way, so I downvoted and left an explanation in the "other" field.

Now I show up as also requesting improvement, but the justification I entered has been lost.  Instead, it shows two votes for the original request:

[image]

I think while this behavior makes sense for most of the downvote reasons, votes should not be consolidated on the "other" reason.  That way, if there are multiple issues with an example, an editor can identify and address all of them at once.

Comment: Not only "other" downvotes are collapsed into one item, but flags too. I flagged [Sorting Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/3813/sorting-arrays) topic, chose "moderator intervention", entered text, and it disappeared too. Looks like I just increased the "other" counter. What's funny, I can't upvote someone's comment directly.